# How to start server and client through one shell script with small validation

Tags: shell

I need to check whether the server has started or not automatically. if the server has started then need to start the client. if not execution need to be stopped. I am using shell script to start the server. Basically my plan is log the terminal results in to the text file and check for the word called "Test server started". if the word exists then client will start, if not whole execution should be terminated.

This is my run script

```
    #!/bin/bash

    CLASSPATH=.:target/classes:target/parent-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
    JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"

    HOST="localhost"
    PORT="9893"

    FULL_EXPERIMENT_PERIOD=15
    WARM_UP_PERIOD=10

    FILENAME="/home/james/projects/streamperf/git/benchmarks-local/sample.txt"

    java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH org.wso2.sp.tcp.server.TCPServer $HOST $PORT $FULL_EXPERIMENT_PERIOD $WARM_UP_PERIOD &

    if grep -q "Test server started" "$FILENAME";then
        sh client.sh

    fi
```

According to this run script if clause is being checked after i stopped the server. but i need to check that one after i start the server (it should be done automatically). How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `until` and `netcat` (or `nc`) to test if your TCP server is up. Here's a modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CLASSPATH=.:target/classes:target/parent-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8g -Xms8g"

HOST="localhost"
PORT="9893"

FULL_EXPERIMENT_PERIOD=15
WARM_UP_PERIOD=10

FILENAME="/home/james/projects/streamperf/git/benchmarks-local/sample.txt"

java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH org.wso2.sp.tcp.server.TCPServer $HOST $PORT $FULL_EXPERIMENT_PERIOD $WARM_UP_PERIOD &

# create test file
echo "" > test.txt

until nc $HOST $PORT < test.txt
do
    echo "waiting for tcp server..."
    sleep 1
fi

sh client.sh
```

This script will wait until the command `nc $HOST $PORT < test.txt` returns a 0 exit code and move on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But according to this script will the client script work automatically after server's up? I tried but it's not

Comment: @James Sorry, maybe I misunderstood the question. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "client script work automatically". The script I posted will just wait for the TCP server to start listening and then run the client script. If you need to actually parse the output of the server then I'll point you to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117502